# Although the Intesis Modbus adaptor in my heat pump does give me its baud rate, it tells me there is no contact

Tags: python, modbus, raspberry-pi4, rs485, minimalmodbus

I run a Raspberry Pi 4 with a [USB-RS485 adaptor](https://minielektro.dk/usb-til-rs485-konverter.html?gclid=CjwKCAjw-L-ZBhB4EiwA76YzOStCx5RDpbV-BtdMHHjm8hDNIwL9kEBZ6ErAvpe9wAb41INBXNh1hxoCfvAQAvD_BwE) connected to a [Panasonic IntesisBox](https://www.computersalg.dk/i/4553583/panasonic-mbs-modbus-paw-aw-mbs-h-til-h-og-j-generation-luft-vand-varmepumpe), using the Python [minimalmodbus module](https://pypi.org/project/minimalmodbus/). First, I check the connection by this function:

```
import minimalmodbus

def openandcheckModbuscom():
    print('---openandcheckModbuscom----------------')
    # call the Modbus interface
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')  # open serial port
    if ser.is_open:
        print('Serial port is open with the following settings:')
        print(ser.is_open)      # TRUE if port is open
        print(ser.name)         # print actual port name
        print(ser.baudrate)     # print port baudrate
    else:
        print('Serial port not open yet, sorry :-(')
       
    ser.close()
```

When executed, it returns: TRUE, /dev/ttyUSB0 and 9600, so I think all is fine. Next, I want to get more data from the interface and also save data in my database, so I run:

```
def readHPstatus():
    print('---readHPstatus----------------')
    # call the Modbus interface
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')  # open serial port
    instrument = minimalmodbus.Instrument('/dev/ttyUSB0', 1) 
 
    # Read various temperatures
    outdoortemp = instrument.read_register(1, 0) 
    print(outdoortemp)
 
    outgoingtemp = instrument.read_register(2, 0) 
    print(outgoingtemp)
 
    ingoingtemp = instrument.read_register(3, 0) 
    print(ingoingtemp)
 
    tanktemp = instrument.read_register(32, 0) 
    print(tanktemp)
 
    setpointtemp = instrument.read_register(33, 0) 
    print(setpointtemp)
 
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO HPstatus VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,);", (Rightnow, outdoortemp, outgoingtemp, ingoingtemp, tanktemp, setpointtemp))
 
    ser.close()
```

But that returns only the error message of no connection to the interface. How come, when I have just received both a confirmation of the port and the baud rate...? How do I get the second part going?

Full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cpoll/pycode/pollvp010.py", line 260, in <module>
    readHPstatus()
  File "/home/cpoll/pycode/pollvp010.py", line 179, in readHPstatus
    outdoortemp = instrument.read_register(1, 0)  # Registernumber, number of decimals
  File "/home/cpoll/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/minimalmodbus.py", line 480, in read_register
    returnvalue = self._generic_command(
  File "/home/cpoll/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/minimalmodbus.py", line 1245, in _generic_command
    payload_from_slave = self._perform_command(functioncode, payload_to_slave)
  File "/home/cpoll/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/minimalmodbus.py", line 1322, in _perform_command
    response_bytes = self._communicate(request_bytes, number_of_bytes_to_read)
  File "/home/cpoll/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/minimalmodbus.py", line 1490, in _communicate
    raise NoResponseError("No communication with the instrument (no answer)")
minimalmodbus.NoResponseError: No communication with the instrument (no answer)
```

**Revision on Oct, 11th**

Revised code:

```py
import sqlite3
import requests
import datetime
import json
import serial
import minimalmodbus

def readHPstatus():
    print('---readHPstatus----------------')
    # call the Modbus interface
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')
    
    minimalmodbus.MODE_RTU
    minimalmodbus.BYTEORDER_BIG
    # print(minimalmodbus._getDiagnosticString())
    
    IntesisBox = minimalmodbus.Instrument('/dev/ttyUSB0', 1, debug = True)  # port name, slave address (in decimal)
    IntesisBox.serial.baudrate = 9600
    IntesisBox.serial.parity = minimalmodbus.serial.PARITY_NONE
    IntesisBox.serial.bytesize = 8
    IntesisBox.serial.stopbits = 2
    IntesisBox.serial.timeout = 0.5
    
    IntesisBox.clear_buffers_before_each_transaction = True
    IntesisBox.close_port_after_each_call = True
    
    
    if ser.is_open:
        
        print('Serial port is open with the following settings:')
        print('__Serial port at device:', ser.name)
        print('__Serial port baudrate: ', ser.baudrate)
    
        # Read various temperatures
        
        OutdoorTemp = IntesisBox.read_register(1, 0)
        print('Outdoor Temperature: ', OutdoorTemp)
 
        OutGoingTemp = IntesisBox.read_register(2, 0)
        print('Outgoing Temperature:', OutGoingTemp)
 
        InGoingTemp = IntesisBox.read_register(3, 0)
        print('Ingoing Temperature: ', InGoingTemp)
 
        TankTemp = IntesisBox.read_register(32, 0)
        print('Tank Temperature:    ', TankTemp)
 
        SetpointTemp = IntesisBox.read_register(33, 0)
        print('Setpoint Temperature:', SetpointTemp)
    
        cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO HPstatus VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (Rightnow, OutdoorTemp, OutGoingTemp, InGoingTemp, TankTemp, SetpointTemp))
 
    else:
        print('Serial port not open yet, sorry :-(')
        
    ser.close()
   
    print('---END-------------------\n')
```

Output from running the code:

```
---readHPstatus----------------
MinimalModbus debug mode. Create serial port /dev/ttyUSB0
Serial port is open with the following settings:
__Serial port at device: /dev/ttyUSB0
__Serial port baudrate:  9600
MinimalModbus debug mode. Will write to instrument (expecting 7 bytes back): 01 03 00 01 00 01 D5 CA (8 bytes)
MinimalModbus debug mode. Clearing serial buffers for port /dev/ttyUSB0
MinimalModbus debug mode. No sleep required before write. Time since previous read: 152782414.06 ms, minimum silent period: 4.01 ms.
MinimalModbus debug mode. Closing port /dev/ttyUSB0
MinimalModbus debug mode. Response from instrument: 01 03 02 00 00 B8 44 (7 bytes), roundtrip time: 0.0 ms. Timeout for reading: 500.0 ms.

Outdoor Temperature:  0
MinimalModbus debug mode. Will write to instrument (expecting 7 bytes back): 01 03 00 02 00 01 25 CA (8 bytes)
MinimalModbus debug mode. Opening port /dev/ttyUSB0
MinimalModbus debug mode. Clearing serial buffers for port /dev/ttyUSB0
MinimalModbus debug mode. No sleep required before write. Time since previous read: 6.31 ms, minimum silent period: 4.01 ms.
MinimalModbus debug mode. Closing port /dev/ttyUSB0
MinimalModbus debug mode. Response from instrument: 01 03 02 00 00 B8 44 (7 bytes), roundtrip time: 0.0 ms. Timeout for reading: 500.0 ms.

Outgoing Temperature: 0
MinimalModbus debug mode. Will write to instrument (expecting 7 bytes back): 01 03 00 03 00 01 74 0A (8 bytes)
MinimalModbus debug mode. Opening port /dev/ttyUSB0
MinimalModbus debug mode. Clearing serial buffers for port /dev/ttyUSB0
MinimalModbus debug mode. No sleep required before write. Time since previous read: 5.67 ms, minimum silent period: 4.01 ms.
MinimalModbus debug mode. Closing port /dev/ttyUSB0
MinimalModbus debug mode. Response from instrument: 01 03 02 00 00 B8 44 (7 bytes), roundtrip time: 0.0 ms. Timeout for reading: 500.0 ms.

Ingoing Temperature:  0
MinimalModbus debug mode. Will write to instrument (expecting 7 bytes back): 01 03 00 20 00 01 85 C0 (8 bytes)
MinimalModbus debug mode. Opening port /dev/ttyUSB0
MinimalModbus debug mode. Clearing serial buffers for port /dev/ttyUSB0
MinimalModbus debug mode. No sleep required before write. Time since previous read: 6.64 ms, minimum silent period: 4.01 ms.
MinimalModbus debug mode. Closing port /dev/ttyUSB0
MinimalModbus debug mode. Response from instrument: 01 03 02 00 00 B8 44 (7 bytes), roundtrip time: 0.0 ms. Timeout for reading: 500.0 ms.

Tank Temperature:     0
MinimalModbus debug mode. Will write to instrument (expecting 7 bytes back): 01 03 00 21 00 01 D4 00 (8 bytes)
MinimalModbus debug mode. Opening port /dev/ttyUSB0
MinimalModbus debug mode. Clearing serial buffers for port /dev/ttyUSB0
MinimalModbus debug mode. No sleep required before write. Time since previous read: 7.87 ms, minimum silent period: 4.01 ms.
MinimalModbus debug mode. Closing port /dev/ttyUSB0
MinimalModbus debug mode. Response from instrument: 01 03 02 00 00 B8 44 (7 bytes), roundtrip time: 0.0 ms. Timeout for reading: 500.0 ms.

Setpoint Temperature: 0
---END-------------------
```

Comment: Please provide the full error message. Opening the port does not verify connectivity (you can successfully open the port with whatever baud rate you like but if the device is not configured for that rate it will not receive what you send). Based upon [this manual](https://www.panasonicproclub.com/uploads/ES/catalogues/manual-instalacion/Manual%20PAW-AW-MBS-H_User_Manual_v1.2_r1.3_EN.pdf) you probably need 9600 8N2) but check the DIP switches for baud rate, slave ID etc. At this point it's also still possible there is a wiring issue.

Comment: Just to clarify the `ser.baudrate` you are seeing is the configuration of your local port (the RS485 adapter); this value has not come from the Intesis unit (your first program does not actually communicate with the Intesis unit at all; it just opens the local port).

Comment: Oh, okey, thanks for that clarification. I will return with the full error message later today.

Comment: My wire from the adaptor to the IntesisBox is only like 10 meters long, so no resistors have been installed. Do you say, I should set the DIP switches to 9600 if they are not? What else may be the problem?

Comment: Currently there are many potential problems (comms setting mismatch, incorrect wiring, faulty unit or RS485 adapter, incorrect slave ID etc). The comms settings you us on the PC (and you [control these](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial) must match the device configuration (as per manual and DIP switches) so I'd start there. It might be beneficial to use a known good application (e.g. [modpoll](https://www.modbusdriver.com/modpoll.html)/[mbpoll](https://github.com/epsilonrt/mbpoll)) to confirm that the device is reachable before writing your own code.

Comment: I have now added the error messages.

Comment: That is the error I was expecting. You might find that enabling [debug mode](https://minimalmodbus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/debugmode.html) provides more info (but I'd guess the command is being sent and nothing is coming back).

Answer (score 2):

First off remove these lines:

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')  # open serial port
...
ser.close()
```

Minimalmodbus is already instantiating the serial port for you. Regarding your first code snippet you say:

> When executed, it returns: TRUE, /dev/ttyUSB0 and 9600, so I think all is fine.

Well... if by *all is fine* you mean you are able to set up your serial port you are right, but as I said above minimalmodbus is creating an instance of the serial port itself, and its baudrate is by default 19200, so you need to add these line after you create your instrument:

```
instrument.serial.baudrate = 9600
```

Then, according to the IntesisBox [manual](https://www.panasonicproclub.com/uploads/ES/catalogues/manual-instalacion/Manual%20PAW-AW-MBS-H_User_Manual_v1.2_r1.3_EN.pdf) (page 7):

*PAW-AW-MBS-H implements a Modbus RTU (Slave) interface, to be connected to an EIA-485
line. **It performs 8N2 communication (8 data bits, no parity and 2 stop bit)** with several
available baud rates (2400 bps, 4800 bps, 9600 bps -default-, 19200 bps, 38400 bps, 57600
bps, 76800 bps and 115200 bps). It also supports 8N1 communication (8 data bits, no parity
and 1 stop bit).*

As I understand it, the device should work with both 8N1 and 8N2 with no problems but you might want to change minimalmodbus' configuration and give it a try:

```
instrument.serial.stopbits = 2
```

If none of the above is helping you should probably pay attention to Brits' comments and check all those DIP switches and use something like [QModMaster](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qmodmaster/) to debug your settings before writing any code.

Last but not least, make sure your wiring is correct. For Modbus you actually need three wires: A, B and **GND**. For more details you can refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66905927/minimalmodbus-randomly-generates-wrong-crc). Looking at the picture of your USB-to-RS485 I can see it's one of those with no provision for a GND wire. Heck, neither is there one on the IntesisBox... You'll probably have to check where the GND is on that hydro unit (whatever that might be) and connect it to one of the ground pins on the RPi [header](https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2012/06/simple-guide-to-the-rpi-gpio-header-and-pins/).

Reading the title of your question I'm guessing your understanding of how the serial port works is a bit off. Be aware that what you are doing on your first code snippet is **all happening** on the local serial port connected to your RPi. Your *Intesis is **not** giving your its baudrate*, because it is simply not giving you anything at all and hence this line on the log:

```
minimalmodbus.NoResponseError: No communication with the instrument (no answer)
```

Although some devices are able to negotiate their baudrates automatically, yours is certainly not. Yet some other devices store their settings, including their baudrate in registers that are accessible through Modbus, but that's not the case with yours either. So I'm afraid the only way for your device to give you its baudrate is for you to look at the position of those DIP switches.

Comment: Well caught - I totally missed the fact that the `serial.Serial` call was redundant. I might revert to my first answer always being "use a known good app to verify connectivity before writing your own code"; there are just too many variables when you don't even know if the wiring is correct.

Comment: thanks. Yes, that would be my first piece of advice too. It is surprising how something so simple has so many failure modes. That's why you have to go back to the basics and keep ticking boxes one at a time...

Comment: Thanks a lot to @Brits and @Marcos-G. I checked the wiring etc and realized that the A and B wires were mixed up. Very simple, so now I seem to be "in", but I get only zeros when reading, like: `outdoortemp = instrument.read_register(1, 0) 
    print(outdoortemp)`. Do you have any ideas on where to dig for solutions on that?

Comment: you mean all registers you read contain zeros? Register 4, for instance, should return values from 1 to 11, but never zero. Have you tried running QModMaster? that should help troubleshoot the connections and configuration before you get busy writing code.

Comment: I have been looking at the web page of QModMaster, and it looks a lot more complicated to me to find out how to install and understand this tool on my RaspberryPi, compared to give it a try with different code lines, using minimalmodbus. I am not a programmer nor have any experience with technical protocols - only a chemical engineer, trying to save some money on energy prices, controlling my heat pump with an IntesisBox. The code seems pretty straight forward. I just need some hints to where the problems may be, I hope, and thank you so much so far :-)

Comment: So, I try to get some data from the heat pump, using:

`OutdoorTemp = IntesisBox.read_register(1, 0) 
 print('Outdoor Temperature: ', OutdoorTemp)
 OutGoingTemp = IntesisBox.read_register(2, 0)  
 print('Outgoing Temperature:', OutGoingTemp)
 InGoingTemp = IntesisBox.read_register(3, 0)  
 print('Ingoing Temperature: ', InGoingTemp)
 TankTemp = IntesisBox.read_register(32, 0)  
 print('Tank Temperature:    ', TankTemp)
 SetpointTemp = IntesisBox.read_register(33, 0)  
 print('Setpoint Temperature:', SetpointTemp)`

They all result in 0

Comment: Output when I run the program:

Outdoor Temperature:  0
Outgoing Temperature: 0
Ingoing Temperature:  0
Tank Temperature:     0
Setpoint Temperature: 0

Comment: By the way, it is this IntesisBox for Panasonic Aquarea Monoblok heat pump: https://www.intesis.com/products/ac-interfaces/modbus-gateways/panasonic-modbus-air-to-water-pa-aw2-mbs-1?ordercode=INMBSPAN001A000

Comment: Can you edit your question to show all code you are running verbatim? While you are at it change the line where you define your instrument to activate debug mode: `instrument = minimalmodbus.Instrument('/dev/ttyUSB1', 1, debug = True)` and post also the full output.

Comment: For the record, I think you still have hardware issues. All those zeros make no sense to me.

Comment: Dear @Marcos-g, all code and output now added as you requested. Thanks.

Comment: Well, everything seems to be working, but the contents of those registers should not be zero. Have you tried reading the maintenance registers (error code, device status, and current error status), see manual pages 11 and 21 for the error codes. Other than malfunctioning, I cannot think of any reason to give you zeros in all those registers.

Comment: This [library](https://github.com/gianfrdp/pyModbusIntesisBox) might have something useful for your problem.

Comment: Thanks, the maintenance registers on page 11 also give zeros...
The library, you linked to, is for pyModbusIntesisBox. I have so far used minimalmodbus. Do you think I should shift? Or are they related in some way that I do not understand?

Comment: You are welcome. The library you use should not matter, all of them should give you the same results but with these open-source libraries sometimes you have mysterious issues and it might be worthwhile exploring as many options as you can. My advice would be to make sure every component works on its own before putting them together. If you have other Modbus devices, use your minimalmodbus setup with them to see if they work, or try to connect your Intesis to a different computer with a different USB serial port.

Comment: If you can get hold of a Windows or Linux laptop you should reconsider trying something like QModMaster. If is a very simple tool, see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UsLeZkdNoh8).

Comment: Those round-trip times of zero seem very strange to me, maybe something is messed up with minimal...

Comment: Now I did download and run the QModMaster on my windows laptop. I can't get it to connect... It says: "Connecting to serial port [COM1]....Failed"

Comment: you might need to go check on the device manager if your USB port is named COM1, and also make sure the baud rate, stop bits, and all that is OK too, and don't forget the unit ID (slave address). If you are not able to establish a connection with QModMaster I would bet something is wrong with either your USB adaptor or your Intesis (that's obviously assuming your wiring is fine, and be aware that a GND common to both devices is very important if you are running your laptop from its battery).

Comment: It might be a good idea to connect your laptop's power supply to the same AC outlet where your hydro unit, boiler, or whatever is feeding from to have a common ground. With a laptop running on battery, GND is always a headache.

Comment: The problem has finally been solved: It appeared that the IntesisBox was a wrong version for the heat pump. I have now got the right version installed, and it works with my code, the USB adapter and the Raspberry Pi 4. Thanks for all your contributions, @MarcosG. and also Brits

Comment: you are welcome. I'm glad to hear you managed to get it to work. This kind of compatibility is very frustrating indeed.

Comment: Yes, very frustrating. Only one letter difference between IntesisBox model's names does not make it easier (PAW-AW-MBS was correct, while they first installed the PA-AW-MBS...). I am happy that I did not have problems with grounding, baud rate, timeout etc. You were so right: I had hardware problems :-)